# What does $a\equiv b\pmod n$ mean?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What does the $\equiv$ and $b\pmod n$ mean?

for example, what does the following equation mean?

$5x \equiv 7\pmod {24}$? Tomorrow I have a final exam so I really have to know what is it.

Comment: It means that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$. Equivalently, it means that $n$ divides $a-b$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I do because most of the exam is about group theory ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s a bit late to be learning a basic definition, but here it is: $a\equiv b\pmod n$ means that $n\mid a-b$, i.e., that $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$. Thus, the congruence $5x\equiv 7\pmod{24}$ means that $24\mid 5x-7$. To solve it, you must find an integer $x$ that makes this true. Since $5\cdot11-7=55-7=48$ is a multiple of $24$, $x\equiv 11\pmod{24}$ is a solution.

Comment: Great answer .. thank you. how is that called in english? I'd like to search more in google but I don't know what to search ..

Comment: But definitions is all you need to work with $\ddot \smile$

Comment: @user1798362 Check the tags to the question: [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: @user1798362: You’re welcome. This notion of $\equiv$ is called *congruence*: $a$ is *congruent* to $b$ modulo $n$. $5x\equiv 7\pmod{24}$ is an example of a *linear congruence*. Arithmetic with congruences is often called *modular arithmetic*.

Answer (score 5):

> $a\equiv b\pmod n \Longleftrightarrow$ there is an integer $k$ such that $kn+b=a$

Comment: Thanks for your support and +

Answer (score 3):

$a\equiv b\;(mod\;n) \iff b-a=$ multiple of $n$.
So $5x\equiv 7\;(mod\;24) \iff 5x-7=24k$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=qn+r_{1}$ and $b=pn+r_{2}$, where $0\leq r_{1},r_{2}<n$. Then $$r_{1}=r_{2}.$$

$r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ are remainders when $a$ and $b$ are divided by $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of thinking: $a\equiv b\pmod n$ means that the remainder of $a$ divided by $n$ is equal to the remainder of $b$ divided by $n$.

Answer (score 1):

It means $5x-7$ is divisible by $24$. $(5x-7)/24$ is an integer.

Comment: @Daniel thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As $\lambda(24)=$lcm$(\lambda(3),\lambda(8))=$lcm$(2,2)=2$

Using [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $a^2\equiv1\pmod{24}$ if $(a,1)=24$

or clearly, $5^2\equiv1\pmod{24}$

So, $5x\equiv7\pmod {24}\implies 5^2x\equiv7\cdot5\pmod{24}\implies x\equiv 35\equiv11\pmod {24} $